# Can you get the readme.md for a private repository using Github's API?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, github, github-api

I have been having a play around with Github's API and also gave Octokit a try but cant seem to figure out if it is possible to access private repository's readme's to return the content for the logged in user?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible using the Github Api v3, there is a dedicated endpoint for fetching the readme content:
`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/readme`

Check out the docs: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that